# Adding a toolbar to the result of an UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i´m having a tough time with `UISearchDisplayController`. In my scenario i have an `UIView` pushed onto a navgation controller. In the `UIView` i have an `UITableView` and `UIToolbar`. In the `UITableView` I´m using `UISearchDisplayController`.

[image: <img></img>]

The toolbar buttons are used to add additional filter options to the search. My problem is that I can´t figure out, how to add the toolbar at the bottom of the result table view of the `UISearchDisplayController`.

[image]

What is the way to go to add a toolbar to the results?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my problem.

Instead of using UISearchDisplayController i only add a UISearchBar to my UITableView and replicate the behavior of UISearchDisplayController with the UISearchBarDelegate methods.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self setSearchText:searchText];
    [self filterCards];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    [self setScopeIndex:selectedScope];
    [self filterCards];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // Move searchbar to table view
    [self.chapterSearchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.chapterTableView addSubview:[self chapterSearchBar]];

    // Show navigation controller
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    // Hide scope bar an resize
    [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:NO];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    // Hide cancel button
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];

    // Resize table view
    CGRect tableViewRect = [self.chapterTableView frame];    
    tableViewRect.origin.y = 0;
    [self.chapterTableView setFrame:tableViewRect];

    // Hide keyboard
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self setSearchText:@""];
    [self filterCards];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // Move searchbar to controller view
    [self.chapterSearchBar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:[self chapterSearchBar]];

    // Hide navigation controller
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    // Show scope bar an resize
    [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    // Show cancel button
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    // Resize table view
    CGRect tableViewRect = [self.chapterTableView frame];    
    tableViewRect.origin.y = 44;
    [self.chapterTableView setFrame:tableViewRect];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's curious how to solve this issue with still using `UISearchDisplayController` (cleaner probably), simply set the items of your toolbar to your view controller's `toolbarItems` while search is active:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
self.toolbarItems = optionsToolbar.items;
```

The `UISearchDisplayController` retains the view controller's toolbar according to `toolbarItems`, so this might already be done for you. Can be useful if the toolbar is only being used during search.